# How to modify a holder (ImageView) inside an inner class?

Tags: android, fragment, global-variables, uri, inner-classes

I have an Adapter called ObjetoAdapter which have a ViewHolder called MyViewHolder with and ImageView "fotoObjeto".Inside this adapter there is an inner class

```
storageReference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();
StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child(objeto.getNome() + ".jpg");

childRef.getDownloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener{
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

     Log.i("OA7.1","objeto.getnome() uri: " + uri );
     Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(uri).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);
}
```

The fact is that i've tried to retrieve (by all manners) the "uri" outside this addOnSuccessListener{...}, with no success. Also, i've used SharedPreferences to store this value, like the following:

```
storageReference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();
StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child(objeto.getNome() + ".jpg");

childRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.i("OA7.1","objeto.getnome() uri: " + uri );
                Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(uri).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext().getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("KEY",uri.toString());
            }
        });

        if(sharedPreferences.contains("KEY")){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse( sharedPreferences.getString("KEY",null) );
            Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(uri).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);
        }
```

But even after those tries, i've realized that the sharedPreferences saves an apparently wrong uri.In other words, shared preferences saves a uri, but isn't the same as original. There are no other shared Key like that.
I need help and i've "cleaned" Google trying to find a solution to this trick.
Any help is welcome.Thanks in advance!

Down here i`ll put all the fragment code:

```
package com.mypackage

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.storage.StorageManager;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.R;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.activity.LoginActivity;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.activity.MeuItemActivity;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.config.ConfiguracaoFirebase;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.helper.Base64Custom;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.helper.ImageProcess;
import com.droidelivery.droidelivery.model.Objeto;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Lucas on 16/09/2017.
 */

public class ObjetoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Objeto> {
    private ArrayList<Objeto> objetos;
    private Context context;
    private FirebaseUser usuarioLogado;
    private ImageView fotoObjeto;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private Button botaoExcluir;
    private DatabaseReference dataBaseReference;
    private DatabaseReference dataBaseReferenceGeral;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    //private int i = 0;
    private int itemAba;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String bitmapString;




    public ObjetoAdapter(@NonNull Context c, @NonNull ArrayList<Objeto> objects) {
        super(c, 0, objects);
        this.objetos = objects;
        this.context = c;
    }

    class MyViewHolder{
        ImageView fotoObjeto;
        TextView nomeObjeto;
        TextView emailObjeto;
        Button botaoExcluir;

        MyViewHolder(View v){

            nomeObjeto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nome);
            emailObjeto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            botaoExcluir = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.botaoExcluirId);
            fotoObjeto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_objeto_id);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        //Log.i("DDD8(ObjetoAdapter)","getView CHAMADO!!! " );
        Log.i("OA1","position(ObjetoAdapter): " + position );
        View view = null;

        View row = convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if( row == null ){
            //inicializar objeto para montagem da view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_objeto, parent , false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        //Recebe qual foi a última aba da MainActivity
        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( getContext() );
        Log.i("OA2","getContext(): " + getContext() );
        if( sharedPreferences.contains("CURRENT_ITEM") ){
            itemAba = sharedPreferences.getInt("CURRENT_ITEM",0);
            Log.i("OA3","itemAba:" + itemAba );
        }

            usuarioLogado = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao().getCurrentUser();
            dataBaseReference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("objetos").child( Base64Custom.codificarBase64( usuarioLogado.getEmail() ) );
            dataBaseReferenceGeral = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("geral");
            storageReference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();

            Log.i("OA4","storageReference: " + storageReference);




        holder.fotoObjeto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"PODE MOSTRAR UMA IMAGEM SOZINHA!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                Log.i("OA5","getContext()" + getContext() );
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MeuItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("POSICAO", position); //passar a posicao do clique na ListView para a MeuItemActivity.java
                getContext().startActivity( intent );

            }
        });


        holder.botaoExcluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                objetos.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

                    dataBaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        int i = 0;
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                                final Objeto objeto = dados.getValue( Objeto.class );
                                Log.i("OA6","objeto.getNome():" + objeto.getNome() + "posicao: " + i);
                                if(i == position ){
                                    Log.i("OA7","objeto.getNome():" + objeto.getNome() + "posicao: " + i + "EXCLUÍDO!");
                                    dataBaseReference.child(dados.getKey()).removeValue();

                                    dataBaseReferenceGeral.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            for(DataSnapshot dadosGeral: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                                                Objeto objetoGeral = dadosGeral.getValue( Objeto.class);

                                                if( objetoGeral.getNome().equals( objeto.getNome() ) &&
                                                    objetoGeral.getDescricao().equals( objeto.getDescricao() ) &&
                                                        objetoGeral.getUrl().equals( objeto.getUrl() )

                                                   ){
                                                        dataBaseReferenceGeral.child(dadosGeral.getKey()).removeValue();
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                            }
                        });

            final Objeto objeto = objetos.get( position );
            holder.nomeObjeto.setText( objeto.getNome() );
            holder.emailObjeto.setText( usuarioLogado.getEmail() );
            //Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(objeto.getUrl()).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);
            //Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(objeto.getUrl()).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);
            //holder.fotoObjeto.setImageBitmap(ImageProcess.getBitmapFromURL(objeto.getUrl()));
            //Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load().override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);


        //final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        storageReference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();
        StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child(objeto.getNome() + ".jpg");
        childRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.i("OA7.1","objeto.getnome() uri: " + uri );
                Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(uri).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext().getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("KEY",uri.toString());
            }
        });

        if(sharedPreferences.contains("KEY")){
            Uri uri = Uri.parse( sharedPreferences.getString("KEY",null) );
            Glide.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(uri).override(100, 200).into(holder.fotoObjeto);
        }

            Log.i("OA8","objetos.size = " + objetos.size()); //numero de elementos da lista (confirmado!)

        if(sharedPreferences.contains("link")){
            String link = sharedPreferences.getString("link","");
                    Log.i("OA9","link(ObjetoAdapter) = " + link);
                    Log.i("OA10","objetos.get(position).getUrl(ObjetoAdapter) = " + objetos.get(position).getUrl());
            Toast.makeText(context, "link: " + link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //final MyViewHolder finalHolder = holder;

        return row;
        }
        //return view;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this Uri? If you don't want to save it for later DON'T store them in the Shared Preferences! But in any case you forgot to commit after putting the String, that's why it's not stored. But please refactor your code. You can't have a listener inside a listener inside a listener...  (And code in English, especially if you want us to help you.)

Comment: The commit i`ve already fixed before.I only posted the old code.By the way, using Log.i i`ve discovered that Shared Preferences for some reason was changing the Uri.So, making a function changing this uri solved my problem.